# Qlik sense tool integration with InfluxDB

Tags: rest, influxdb, qliksense

Is there a way by which I could load my data from my InfluxDb database to Qlik Sense tool?
I have tried with REST connector but since it does not allow data from localhost so I cannot use the InfluxDB http API interface.

Thanks for the help, appreciate it

Comment: if your DB is local then you can use QS Desktop to load the data. With QSE then your database should be hosted somewhere

Comment: Ok got it, but where do I host the Db..on some could service or a web server?

Comment: It's entirely up to you. It's better if the DB is "closer" to qlik to avoid network latency